# How to exit recursion in ANSI C

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

I am writing a simple program to calculate the factorials in ANSI C. The program works fine up to 12 because past 13 the numbers become too large for INT. What I want to do is to print the first 12, then somehow **BREAK** and send an error for the 13th number. However, the problem is that when I reach the 13th number and send the error, the first 12 do not print. Is is possible to return the error and still get the first 12?

My code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int getIntFactorial(int x){

printf("Processing factorial of (%d) \n", x);
if (x <=1){
    printf("\n Reached base case, returning %d \n", x);
    printf("Now returning total value \n");
    return 1;
}else if (x < 13){
    printf("\n Doing recursion by calling factorial (%d - 1) \n", x);

    int counter = x * getIntFactorial(x - 1);

    printf("Receiving results of factorial (%d) = %d * %d = %d \n", x, x, (x-1), counter);
    return counter;
}else {
///number is greater than 13
    printf("Sorry, we cannot do the factorial for %d, only goes up to 12 \n", x);
    return;
}



}


main()
{
    getIntFactorial(13);


}
```

**Output for 13:**

```
Processing factorial of (13)
Sorry, we cannot do the factorial for 13, only goes up to 12

Process returned 62 (0x3E)   execution time : 0.009 s
Press any key to continue.
```

**Output for 12:**

```
Processing factorial of (12)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (12 - 1)
Processing factorial of (11)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (11 - 1)
Processing factorial of (10)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (10 - 1)
Processing factorial of (9)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (9 - 1)
Processing factorial of (8)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (8 - 1)
Processing factorial of (7)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (7 - 1)
Processing factorial of (6)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (6 - 1)
Processing factorial of (5)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (5 - 1)
Processing factorial of (4)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (4 - 1)
Processing factorial of (3)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (3 - 1)
Processing factorial of (2)

 Doing recursion by calling factorial (2 - 1)
Processing factorial of (1)

 Reached base case, returning 1
Now returning total value
Receiving results of factorial (2) = 2 * 1 = 2
Receiving results of factorial (3) = 3 * 2 = 6
Receiving results of factorial (4) = 4 * 3 = 24
Receiving results of factorial (5) = 5 * 4 = 120
Receiving results of factorial (6) = 6 * 5 = 720
Receiving results of factorial (7) = 7 * 6 = 5040
Receiving results of factorial (8) = 8 * 7 = 40320
Receiving results of factorial (9) = 9 * 8 = 362880
Receiving results of factorial (10) = 10 * 9 = 3628800
Receiving results of factorial (11) = 11 * 10 = 39916800
Receiving results of factorial (12) = 12 * 11 = 479001600

Process returned 479001600 (0x1C8CFC00)   execution time : 0.015 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining about the lack of a return value in the `else { …; return; }` part of your function.  You need to return something; maybe `0` or `-1` would be usable, or semi-usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of the requirement, Changing `return;` in the last `else` block to `return getIntFactorial(x-1)` would yield the result you want?

Comment: This actually does yield what I want, not as pretty as I thought but it works.

Comment: @user3386436 try getting the factorial of 17 and see what that yields. If you want to print all factorials going up to a number, there's an easier way to do it, instead of the convoluted way you are doing it.

Comment: It will print "Can't do 17, 16 ,15" etc until it reaches 12, then it starts printing normally. Yeah that's what I figured, by doing it backwards its the only way its going to work. I can probably make it look nicer going forward.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking to do here. What is clear is that the behavior you observe is correct, given your code: Of course the factorials for the first twelve number does not print when you try to call `getIntFactorial(13)`. Your code does it that way.

The structure of your `getIntFactorial`, in pseudocode, is this:

```
if the number is less than or equal to 1:
    return 1;
if the number is less than 13:
    return the number times the factorial of the number minus one
if the number is greater than or equal to 13:
    print an error and return nothing
```

Notice, by the way, that in the case where your input is greater than 13, you call `return` without returning anything. Your function claims to return an `int` which is *something*. You return *nothing* which is **very different** than *something*. Your compiler should have complained, and it should have complained loudly. If it didn't, you should get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You could test to see if your parameter is more than 12 first, and if it is, print your error message, and then call your recursive function with 12 as the parameter.

Comment: Thats another possibility I was thinking as well which would work.